# jQuery slideToggle adding space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using `slideToggle` to show/hide a submenu, but whenever I toggle the submenu, a bit of extra space is added to the bottom of the containing element. It is only for a brief second.

Any idea why this is happening?

[You can see the behavior in this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/12/)

**JS**

```
$( ".dd" ).click(function() {
  $( ".submenu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
  });
});
```

Comment: It's related to the margins, the submenu adds `margin-bottom:12px` as well as the parent menu, making it double when you open/close it http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/19/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [margins are collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) and this is causing the jump with slideToggle(). To fix it?

Add

```
li {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3dX3T/23/)**

Comment: This is the best approach to fix the issue without having to make additional padding/margin adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose not to go the extra padding route, this also seems to work.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/22/)

**Updated CSS**

```
header nav > ul > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

header .submenu li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

header nav > ul > li:last-child {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 ;
}
```

Comment: That certainly fixes the jump, but messes up my paddings/margins. But I can [adjust that](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/26/), so this works too.

Answer (score 0):

solution is to add 1px padding instead of 0 padding

```
ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:1px;
}
```

enjoy :)

Comment: Ok...but why? An explanation would be useful for future reference.